# Iterator ofor an image class with generic uint8_t data storage

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have an image class that can store any depth + any precision (e.g. float, double) pixels. My data is stored in an `std::vector<uint8_t> m_pixels;` and then I iterate over the pixels based on the number of channels and precision (in bytes), i.e, to iterate over all the pixels in a RGB float image I would do

```
float *ptr = reinterpret_cast<float*>(m_pixels.data());
int stride = numberOfChannels * sizeof(float);
for (int i = 0; i < imgWidth * imgHeight; i += stride) { 
  float& pixel = ptr[i];
  ...
}
```

(Please forget optimizing that code for now, e.g. moving pointers and so on)

Now I am trying to create an iterator based on `std::iterator`. Lets call it `ImageIter`. I have the following problem: If I make this a templated iterator, I will always have code like:

```
if (image.isFloat()) {
  ImageIter<float> i(image);
  ...
} else if (image.isDouble()) {
  ImageIter<double> i(image);
  ...
}
```

Is there any way to escape this or make this a simpler code without having to always depend on chained if's for iterating over the image?

Comment: Can't image class contain templated parameter with its type and type of an iterator? e.g. `Image<float>::iterator`

Comment: @W.F. you mean a typedef? But how would I do that without chained if's anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Image is a template struct with iterator type defined in it:

```
template <class T>
struct Image {
    using iterator = ImageIter<T>;
    //...
};
```

If you want to make the iteration generic just use the templated function like:

```
template <class T>
void iterateIf(const Image<T> &cit) {
    // do sth if image has T
}

int main() {
    Image<float> floatImage;
    iterateIf(floatImage); //will execute templated iterateIf
}
```

Now if you want to do some specific operations just when the image contains doubles just create `iterateIf` overload:

```
template <class T>
void iterateIf(const Image<T> &cit) {
    // do sth if image has Ts
}

void iterateIf(const Image<double> &cid) {
    // do something only when parameter is Image<double>
}

int main() {
    Image<float> floatImage;
    iterateIf(floatImage); //will execute templated iterateIf
    Image<double> doubleImage;
    iterateIf(doubleImage); //will execute iterateIf(const Image<double>&)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I woud recommend against that design.

Violation of principle of least surprise: your image class is element-type-agnostic, but the iterator is not.

You have various options, all with downsides:

**1. make the image class itself a template**

... and provide assignment / conversion between them

```
template <typename TElement> class Image 
{
  public:
   ...
   template <typename TOtherElement>
   Image(Image<TotherElement const & rhs);
   ...
};
```

This moves the `if (image.is(...))` one level up. Not necessarily better, but less surprising (in a good way).

You can implement a shared interface for image manipulation on top of all of them:

```
class IImageManipulation
{
  public:
    virtual void FlipH() = 0;
    virtual void FlipV() = 0;
    virtual void Rotate(float angleDegrees) = 0;
    ...
    virtual void ~IImageManipulation() {}
};

template <typename TElement>
class Image : public IImageManipulation
{
   // ... also implement the abstract methods
}
```

[edit] re *"

I cannot make this a templated image class, because I need to import images from files in any depth and any number of pixels"*:

```
unique_ptr<IImageManipulation> LoadImage(....)
{
   // inspect stream what depth and pixel format you use
   ..
   // create instance
   unique_ptr<IImageManipulation> img = CreateImage(pixeltype);

   // ... and load
   img->Load(file);
}

// Image factory function:
unique_ptr<IImgManipulation> CreateImage(PixelType type)
{
   switch (pixeltype) 
   {  
     case ptFloat: return unique_ptr<IImageManipulation>(new Image<float>()); 
     ...
   }
}
```

your container would store `unique_ptr<IImageManipulation>`.

The idea is to move all generic image manipulation to the interface. 
This is *not* good for pixel-level manipulation, which needs to be implemented in, or using, the `Image` template. However, for image-level manipulation, this is good.

**2. Make the iterator type-agnostic**

i.e. the iterator is not templated, but iterates over an "Pixel" type which can handle all the different pixel formats.

Ideally, the  iterator would implement the pixel format conversion:

```
Image imgf = MakeImage<float>(...);  // an image storing floats
for(Image::iterator it = imgf.begin(); ...) 
{
   Pixel & p = *it;  // type of the iterator elements

   float f = p.asFloat();  // read as float
   int i = p.asInt32();    // read as int, convert in the fly

   p = Pixel.FromRGB(17, 23, 432); // set as int, convert on the fly
   p = Pixel.FromFloat(0.23); 
}
```

Note that the conversion can be made implicit, but this might be a problem if you have different pixel formats with different base types (e.g. 32 bit RGBA vs. ABGR)

Making such a conversion efficient in inner loops might not be trivial.

Comment: I cannot make this a templated image class, because I need to import images from files in any depth and any number of pixels, and store them in a global container (even if they have different types).
I just need an elegant way to create iterators

Comment: @manatttta so you just need a way to iterate your image using given iterator type? But in this case on what base you answer e.g. the image `isFloat()`?

Comment: @W.F. sorry I did not understand the question

Comment: @W.F. I just want an elegant alternative to chained `if (img.isFloat()) else if (img.isDouble())`

Comment: @manatttta OK then, have you considered storing the type inside img e.g. in enum field `type` and store map of `std::function<void()>` each function for different type of your image then call `mymap[img.type]()`;

Comment: @manatttta: see edit. And you still have the second option :)